# PHP Login with bCrypt

Tags: php, bcrypt

I'm trying to switch from SHA1 to bCrypt for passwords.
Register is working but i'm having issues with login.
Could anyone help me out?

This is what i have and it is not working.

```
$SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password"); 
$passwordverified = password_verify($password);
$SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $passwordverified));
$countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);
```

password_verify function

```
function password_verify($password, $hash) {
    if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
        trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_verify to function", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    $ret = crypt($password, $hash);
    if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) != strlen($hash) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
        return false;
    }

    $status = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($ret); $i++) {
        $status |= (ord($ret[$i]) ^ ord($hash[$i]));
    }

    return $status === 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the SQL statement prepared in `$SQLCheckLogin` and also the code you use to register and store the password hash. You are using `password_verify()` incorrectly. You should be retrieving the stored hash with a `SELECT` and the comparing it with the input password as 2 arguments to `password_verify()`.

Comment: $SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");

also i just started with PHP and my skills are limited to just a few things.

Comment: It looks like you may be using an older version of [ircmaxell's `password_verify()`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php#L233) and so you should update that. But if you have PHP 5.5 or later, `password_verify()` is built-in and you do not need the password_compat library at all.

Comment: Can you please edit above to show how you saved the user password hash in the `users` table? I can see the problem with how you are using `password_verify()`, but cannot offer the correct solution unless I am certain of how it was stored in the database.

Comment: Insert as in register?
if so here it is
`$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10));   
$insertUser = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, :username, :password, :email, :scode, 0, 0, 0, 0, :referral, 0, 0)");
$insertUser -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $hash, ':email' => $email, ':scode' => $scode, ':r``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the examples on the official documentation: [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

The function accepts two parameters:

1. The user supplied (plain-text) password
2. The hashed password from the database

The flow for this is:

1. Retrieve the user password *hash* from the database based on the username/emailaddress/whatever identifier
2. Verify the password using `password_verify`

So you code should be something like:

```
$SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username"); 
$SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username));

$hash = $SQLCheckLogin->fetchColumn(0);

if ($hash === false || !password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // you should handle this proper
    die('Failed login');
}

echo 'Logged in';
```

Note that you should also check whether you need to update the hash. The `password_*` API is created with forward compatibility in mind. This means that when there arrives a better / more secure hashing algo available in PHP you can (and should) automatically update you "old" passwords.

The function for this is [`password_needs_rehash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) this checks whether or not the password needs to be updated:

```
$SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username"); 
$SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username));

$hash = $SQLCheckLogin->fetchColumn(0);

if ($hash === false || !password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // you should handle this proper
    die('Failed login');
}

if (password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 14])) {
    $SQLUpdateLogin = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE username = :username"); 
    $SQLUpdateLogin -> execute(array(
        ':username' => $username,
        ':password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 14]),
    ));
}

echo 'Logged in';
```

Comment: That isn't custom-made. It is from password_comapt which backports the functions to PHP 5.3.7 https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php#L233

Comment: I saw no mention about the compat lib. You are right. Updated my answer. @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: I tried using your code and it does not work.

Here's what i use,

http://pastebin.com/qNxnvWKz

Comment: @SevnDK Between Jeeves' code and yours in pastebin, you have missed the line that fetches the `$hash` value from the executed statement: `$hash = $SQLCheckLogin->fetchColumn(0);`  That is needed to compare your input `$password` to the stored hash with `password_verify()`.